# Is it possible to download Docker for all users?

Tags: docker

I am on a virtual machine and have downloaded Docker on my user account. I want to be able for other users to access docker commands and the containers that I have made. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Cameron, can you be more specifc? So, you have downloaded Docker on your host machine or in VM? And which ones you want to create your containers?

Comment: @RobertoGonçalves Downloaded on a VM. It seems that the Engine is a local system service and other people can access my containers fine.

Comment: Hi, Cameron, which OS you are using on your VM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The Docker installation on linux is normally instaled as *root* because it binds to the UNIX Socket (high privilleges), so, on your VM if it's linux you can use this post installation to manage docker as a non-root user:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

So, the other users just have to follow this steps.

And on windows is more simple:

*Containers and images created with Docker Desktop for Windows are shared between all user accounts on machines where it is installed. This is because all Windows accounts use the same VM to build and run containers.* from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/